# What XMPP Servers are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, encryption

I am looking for an XMPP server to install on my ubuntu server, but so far couldn't find any comparisons of the pros and cons of different implementations. Is there an implementation that is a defacto-standard (like, say, apache for http)?

The features the server should have are:

- to play nicely with ubuntu (preferably to already be in the package sources)
- to support encryption
- to be easily configurable over the console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you only have one option: [ejabberd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ejabberd)

The other three available in Ubuntu repo (11.04+) is:

1. jabberd14/jabberd2 not support most of the new XEP, not sure if still actively maintained.
2. prosody is small lua xmpp server, good for test/development but not for production.

You can look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software for some features comparison

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Openfire is fast, easy and reliable.  I have run it under ubuntu server and desktop equally well.  For the average person, I would say use the desktop edition because having that interface just makes it so easy to install and maintain that anyone could handle it.  I have been running my server for well over 5 years, facing the internet and its been a champ.

You can also run it headless in a ubuntu server edition or centos VM using vmplayer with network settings bridged / replicate physical network connection state using 1 or 2 virtual cores.  Its easy.

I recommend this for anyone who isn't going to have thousands upon thousands of simultaneous users online because besides being very easy to install initially, the configuration is via a slick web gui that is really hard to get wrong.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

There is a LAMP stack that is in the repo.
Just use aptitude (open console and type "aptitude" & enter ) and you will see it under the 'Tasks' tree as 'lamp-server'.

Comment: How is LAMP an XMPP server? Or did I misunderdstand your answer?

Comment: Lol sorry about that. I was tired when i say you question but still tried to help. Thought you were asking about XAMPP. My mistake